# How to block redirect on empty request uri

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting all requests to a specific folder by htaccess. Its is working perfect for me. I need to block the redirection on two conditions.

```
mysite.com/admin
```

and when it is empty like

```
mysite.com/
```

By below code the redirect and blocking on admin happens.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /com1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Needs a bit of editing.  I think you are saying that admin blocking you want is working, but blocking on an empty request is not.  Are you asking for help editing the RewriteRule so that it will block empty requests?

Answer (score 0):

You may exit the rule chain early, by not rewriting at all, see [`RewriteRule Substitution`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be a:
>   ...
>   **- (dash)**
>       A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

and the [`L|last`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag.

```
RewriteRule ^admin - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

RewriteRule !/com1/ /com1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```